# How can I hide string contents of an element with CSS?

Tags: html, css

The string is not an element and is generated by a plugin.
I have this code:

```
<div class="form-group">
Show results within             
<input type="number" min="0" id="toolset-maps-distance-value" name="toolset_maps_distance_radius" class="form-control js-toolset-maps-distance-value js-wpv-filter-trigger" value="50" required="">
</div>
```

How can I delete the string "Show results within"?

Comment: `font-size: 0` may do it.

Comment: Thank you very much I had not thought about it...

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't any other text you could change up the form-group class:

- Change the text color to the background color
- Set the Font size to 0.

This "hides" the text. For deleting you probably have to use JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use font-size: 0 on the parent, and then resetting the font-size to the original styles.

```
.form-group {
   font-size: 0; 
}
.form-group input {
   font-size: 14px; // the initial value
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I had not thought about it!

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to get rid off the text completely without using JavaScript or another library you can however set the color to white and the text will be hidden or set the `font-size` to 0;

```css
.form-group{
font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
Show results within             
<input type="number" min="0" id="toolset-maps-distance-value" name="toolset_maps_distance_radius" class="form-control js-toolset-maps-distance-value js-wpv-filter-trigger" value="50" required="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much I had not thought about it!

Answer (score 1):

Use text-indent to offset the text (move it out of the view). You have to set `display: block` on the `input` element though, otherwise it'll be moved as well.

```css
.form-group { text-indent: -999999em; }
input { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  Show results within             
  <input type="number" min="0" id="toolset-maps-distance-value" name="toolset_maps_distance_radius" class="form-control js-toolset-maps-distance-value js-wpv-filter-trigger" value="50" required="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much I had not thought about it!